# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" with Code 9009; command "C:\Program"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, cmd, msbuild

I am using Visual Studio 2010, unfortunately in German, and I get an error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" with Code 9009, see here:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code 9009 beendet.

The output says  command "C:\Program" can't be found.

The error originates here:

```
<CustomBuild
  Sources                     ="@(CustomBuild)"
  BuildSuffix                 ="$(BuildSuffix)"

  TrackerLogDirectory         ="%(CustomBuild.TrackerLogDirectory)"
  MinimalRebuildFromTracking  ="%(CustomBuild.MinimalRebuildFromTracking)"

  TLogReadFiles               ="@(CustomBuildTLogReadFiles)"
  TLogWriteFiles              ="@(CustomBuildTLogWriteFiles)"
  TrackFileAccess             ="$(TrackFileAccess)"
  ToolArchitecture            ="$(CustomBuildToolArchitecture)"
  TrackerFrameworkPath        ="$(CustomBuildTrackerFrameworkPath)"
  TrackerSdkPath              ="$(CustomBuildTrackerSdkPath)"

  AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes  ="%(CustomBuild.AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes)"
  >
</CustomBuild>
```

It seems like some environmental variable is wrong in regards to the spaces. I assume it could be fixed easily by adding "s somewhere, but I don't know where and haven't found anything useful. How can I fix this?

Comment: Put double quotes around the command so the spaces don't byte.  Nobody can tell you exactly where to put them when you don't show the content of the build event in your project.

Comment: Should that information be under Property Pages->Build Events->pre-build/pre-link/post-build? Those are all empty.

Answer (score 2):

I have resloved the issue by moving libraries that I use (qt, osg) in a folder without spaces. I believe the problem was related to qt.